# file in gluster can't be removed or healed

Tags: glusterfs

I have a gluster mounted to a container and they was some issue with one of gluster's brick so I wasn't able to read or write from that mounted dir. I rebooted my entire gluster cluster (I'm using deplicated replicated setup of 4 nodes) and then I ran:

```
gluster volume start vol force
```

which made the brick come back online. but the problem is in my container where gluster is mounted I see the file like this:

```
$ ll
ls: cannot access backups: No such file or directory
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? backups
```

now I can't delete folder backups or access it. I ran :

```
 gluster volume heal gvolume info
```

and the file showed up as: `Possibly undergoing heal`
I ran `gluster volume heal gvolume full` and it returned status as everything was healed successfully but it's not as I still can't access that file.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a similar problem.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did anyone found a solution?